# What is the preferred way of stating (irrelevant) parameters when overriding methods?

Tags: python, oop

Suppose this code:

```
class A:
    def foo(self, bar, baz=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ... # Do some stuff with using bar, baz, args and kwargs
        return result


class B(A):
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ... # Not using bar or baz
        return super().foo(*args, **kwargs)


class C(A):
    def foo(self, bar, baz=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ... # Not using bar or baz
        return super().foo(bar, baz, *args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, there are 2 ways of overriding `foo`. Class C explicitly states the arguments while class B just throws them in `*args` and `*kwargs`. Both work fine. I thought, if I were to use `baz` and `bar` I would explicitly state them as they improve readability, and save me dictionary/list calls. But in case I don't use them, I think wrapping them into `*args` and `**kwargs` should be fine. Is there any preferred way of doing this and any rationale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it. If you don't use `bar`/`baz`, don't accept them, just pass them along as part of `args`/`kwargs` without dealing with them yourself.

[A semi-official recommendation](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) (see the Practical Advice section), especially in more complex inheritance scenarios, is to not accept `*args` at all (barring the off-chance you actually need to accept variable positional arguments, rather than being lazy about not stating the known, fixed number of arguments required by your parents) and have each layer only accept:

1. Arguments they use, and
2. Arbitrary keyword arguments (`**kwargs`)

The reason for this is that:

1. Positional arguments may change position as the hierarchy is modified
2. It gets incredibly ugly figuring out the final ordering of positional arguments when multiple inheritance (or worse, diamond inheritance) gets involved

Requiring all arguments to be passed by keyword is a *little* slower, but it's trivial in the overhead of making many calls via `super()` dispatch, and it's very clear which arguments are being passed and not passed. So for your code, you'd just do:

```
class A:
    def foo(self, bar, baz=None, **kwargs):
        ... # Do some stuff with using bar, baz, and kwargs
        return result

class B(A):
    def foo(self, **kwargs):
        ... # Not using bar or baz
        return super().foo(**kwargs)

class C(A):
    # ... same as B aside from omitted code
```

with callers calling with:

```
instance.foo(bar=1)
instance.foo(bar=2, baz=3)
```

or the like.